# JQuery pagination plugin showing strange results

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I am building a pagination plugin and I am having the strangest results. 
[here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/nEXqQ/)

If you click on the next button (>>) you will be taken to the last page.
But, if you click on the prev button (<<) before you click on the next button you will be taken to the proper page.

Ohh, and if you click on a page number then the next button you will always be taken to the last page.

I've been staring at it for a bit now. boggles me.

Comment: What are the `>>` and `<<` supposed to do? go to the next page or go to the last page?  Also, should it wrap (e.g. if you are on page ten and hit `>>`, should it go to page 1)?

Comment: that is outside of the scope of my question. However it is a good feature. i'll think about adding the option in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this line return a string:

```
 var _to = $(this).attr("id");
```

So that string eventually makes it's way into `current_to` and when you write `current_to + $options.items_pp` you get a string like `1010` instead of `20`.

Just change the line to:

```
var _to = parseInt($(this).attr("id"), 10);
```

Or even better:

```
var _to = parseInt(this.id, 10);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/nEXqQ/110/)